# Show div based on a certain scenario's

Tags: angular

I am trying to only show a div if certain scenario's happen.

---

I get 2 parameters

1. `typeOfCollection` which can have 2 possible values called `branch` or `courier`
2. `duplicate` which can have 2 possible values called `Y` or `N`

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="typeOfCollection === '...' && duplicate" === '...'>
</div>
```

I do not want to show the above div if `typeOfCollection` is `branch` and  `duplicate` is `N`. For any other scenario, I want to show the div. Any idea how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine this would do it:

```html
<div *ngIf="!(typeOfCollection === 'branch' && duplicate" === 'N')">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```html
<div *ngIf="typeOfCollection !== 'branch' || duplicate !== 'N'">
</div>
```

Comment: yes, that wouldn't work as we need to exclude a scenario, so `||` will fail in that situation as it checks for on or the other. @jezmck has the solution

Comment: That would work too, according to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) `!(a && b)` is the same as `!a || !b`, what I wrote.